# Mathquill: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: javascript, npm, electron, mathquill

I'm currently trying to implement MathQuill in a project that I'm working on. I installed the package via NPM (`npm install mathquill`) and put the following `<script>`s in the `<head>`:

```
<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/mathquill/build/mathquill.js"></script>
```

When I load the page, however, I get an error message in Chrome's Dev Tools Console saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at P (mathquill.js:157)
    at mathquill.js:254
    at mathquill.js:4982
P @ mathquill.js:157
(anonymous) @ mathquill.js:254
(anonymous) @ mathquill.js:4982
```

I've looked at other people having similar problems, but none are having the problem I did and I can't seem to resolve it. How should I fix it?

**Edit:**

I figured out the problem. While the docs says JQuery 1.5.2+, it seems to break on whatever the latest version is. I just took the link that they used on their site and it seemed to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was your exact problem but it seems the node package was last updated quite a few years back. Also, the default version of [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/mathquill) points to version 0.9.x which is giving a similar error.

Using the latest version solved the problem. Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/lilb0nd/pen/JjELMBq) with a working example.

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathquill/0.10.1-a/mathquill.min.js'></script>
```

Also, it doesn't seem to be related to the jQuery version as I used: 3.6.0 and it still works.